# Scanner & if-then-else issue

Tags: variables, initialization, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a result (result1) based off of user input. I have gotten an error saying result1 may not have been initiated. If i add it to the code above by inputing `int result1 = 0;` my if-then-else statements causes `system.out.println(result1);` gives me a result of 0 every time. It skips over my if-then-else statements completely. Shouldn't result1 be initiated as soon as the user inputs a string? I appreciate any advice or insight that can be given.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc0 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What would you like to do?: (A)Addition (B)Subtraction (C)Multiplication (D)Division: ");
        String input0 = sc0.nextLine();

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String input1 = sc1.nextLine();

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String input2 = sc2.nextLine();

        int int1 = Integer.parseInt(input1);
        int int2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);


        if (input0 == "A")
        {
            result1 = int1 + int2;
        }
        else if (input0 == "B")
        {
            result1 = int1 - int2;
        }
        else if (input0 == "C")
        {
            result1 = int1 * int2;
        }
        else if (input0 == "D")
        {
            result1 = int1 / int2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid option.");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        System.out.println("Your result is, " + result1 + "!");



    }
}
```

Comment: In Java, variable should be declared first before you can use it. Initialize your int result = 0 and use .equals instead of == for string comparison.

Comment: When i use single =, java gives me an error expecting a boolean. how do i avoid this?

Comment: That is because single (=) equal sign is used as assignment operator. Please check my answer below for the correct string comparison.

Comment: thanks! yeah i knew = is assignment which is why i could not figure out why it wasnt working! clearly im new to coding. thanks a bunch, Mate :)

Comment: No problem. You will soon get familiar with it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use equals instead of the == operator when comparing strings.

```
int result1 = 0;
        Scanner sc0 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What would you like to do?: (A)Addition (B)Subtraction (C)Multiplication (D)Division: ");
        String input0 = sc0.nextLine();

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String input1 = sc1.nextLine();

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String input2 = sc2.nextLine();

        int int1 = Integer.parseInt(input1);
        int int2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);


        if (input0.equals("A"))
        {
            result1 = int1 + int2;
        }
        else if (input0.equals("B"))
        {
            result1 = int1 - int2;
        }
        else if (input0.equals("C"))
        {
            result1 = int1 * int2;
        }
        else if (input0.equals("D"))
        {
            result1 = int1 / int2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid option.");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        System.out.println("Your result is, " + result1 + "!");
```

It always return 0 because you are using == operator, which doesn'e evaulate to either of your IF conditions.